# WSO2 password history limit using SQL Server user store

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a requirement to set Password History limit in WSO2 - IS, i.e if my current password is "password1", and if am trying to changing the password with "password1" again, it should not accept.

If I set my password history limit as "3", then the new password should be different from last 3 password for that particular account.

We are using SQL Server as the user store for WSO2.

Also some previous answers for similar question suggests that I need to implement a custom password policy and add it to wso2. Is that true for version WSO2 IS 4.6.0 ?

Also will this policy apply to both "Forgot your password" and "change password" apis of the wso2 sdk? Or only to change password api?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct. This is not supported by WSO2 Identity Server by default.(Even with latest 5.0.0 version). You need to write a custom password policy implementation by your own to do this. Also, you may need to develop some custom SQL tables to store older password. SQL user store of Identity Server only stores the current password.